# Flexible, fixed div - Need to stick another div to bottom

Tags: html, css

div A is flexible and fixed (to the top of the window) with a high z-index so that items below can pass underneath on scroll.

div B sits underneath div A and I would like for it to "stick" to the bottom of div A as the height flexes when the window is resized. In other words, have the margin between A & B remain consistent.

I fear I have over-thinked this and the solution is simple yet I cannot see it.

The HTML

```
<div id="A">
    some content
</div>

<div id="B">
    some content
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#A {
position: fixed;
z-index: 200;
width: 100%;
}

#B {
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can't you put B into A?

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
  position:fixed;
}

b {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

i think this will work but dont know how it reacts with the fixed instead of relative "a"

Comment: I cannot set B to bottom:0; as I need the top of B to stick to the bottom of A.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put B into A and do this

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/CAF3q/2/

CSS:

```
#a
{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 200px;
    top:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}

#b
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <p>Content of what ever type...</p>
    <p>Content of what ever type...</p>
    <div id="b">
        <p>Everyone is pushing me down 8(</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, see updated link. div A will not reveal contents without a specified height which I cannot set else it defeats the flexible design.

Comment: you did not define this behaviour in your question, The best will be to not have any fixed heights and let the content to it's thing, see updated url above.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something (no surprise). I loaded this example with content to force a scroll and give A something to cause it to resize vertically but no scroll - http://jsfiddle.net/CAF3q/8/

Comment: I think I tried to over-simplify the question in effort to keep it sussinct.

Comment: you can set a max-height if you want scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/CAF3q/9/ If that is not what you want please describe it exactly

Comment: perhaps this (very crude and under development) example will help demonstrate the problem. - http://www.wildflowerevergreen.com/beta/menu.php